# How to automatically detect the last declined call in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I need to detect the last declined call automatically and also need to make the ringtone to mute(off) when an incoming call came pro grammatically in iphone sdk.

Guy's give me your valuable suggestions how to go with this.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Comment: I have the same question. I have tried to find how they did it in Agile Reply with no success. Have you found something?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, sorry. We do not get access to either of those facilities.

Comment: Thanks for ur prompt response.Actually I gone through the Agile reply application in App store.He had done all the features that I asked.If possible can u have a look at that and give any ideas related to it.

Comment: This is the link to that Agile reply application.